# Enabling HTTPS port on a nodeJS application hosted on cPanel

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, cpanel

I have an nodeJS application using express hosted using cPanel on CENTOS 7.9 kvm. Just struggling to get it running with HTTPS inside the nodeJS app.

```
let httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(port);

const httpsServer = https.createServer(sslOptions, app);
httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log("HTTPS Server started")
});
```

The configuration works, but when start with pm2 it shows another process is listening to the SSL port which is "httpd", when I pause "httpd" the application works fine but the process restarts itself and knocks the application offline. Is there anyway to run the application alongside this process? I've looked into port forwarding but not sure how to go about with cPanel.

Thanks

Comment: What is `httpd` being used for this case? You can configure virtual hosts and proxy like in apache2 for different sites.

Comment: what are your sslOptions? how did you get the path to the certificate and key?